# Macro: Copying values from one sheet to another, depending on sheet name, and specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time posting here, pretty new to coding Google Scripts, so I appreciate whatever help I can get.

I'm trying to design a macro and have gone through some threads but haven't found something that fits. I've tried to design the process as program-friendly as I can imagine, hopefully it'll help. The setup is as follows:

- Single Spreadsheet, multiple Sheets. A MainSheet, and an ever increasing amount of secondary Sheets (in the example, there's SheetA and SheetB) [Example Sheet Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tXId.png)
- Column Structure for MainSheet is: SheetName, Date, Column1, Column2. Column Structure for the secondary sheets is always the same: Date, Column 1, Column2. [MainSheet Column Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dKSK.png) [Secondary Sheet Column Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7IHu.png)

The macro is meant to copy data from Column1 and Column2 on MainSheet, and based on the information provided on the SheetName and Date columns, paste it on the respective cells on the secondary sheets. Repeat this process for each entry on MainSheet.

I here an image example of the process: [Example MainSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHQwa.png) [Example SheetA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07sbk.png) [Example SheetB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu1Ls.png)

Again, I'd appreciate whatever help I can get. Thank you very much!

Edit: Here is a [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140ZiF4ZibToRgZLWAWl3oSCSohA3vmya5C5UOgu2nO8/edit?usp=sharing) to the example Google Sheets spreadsheet.

--- Valraz

Comment: Hey Valraz, welcome to Stackoverflow! I would like to know a few things of the date column: how does it behave? Can you have multiple rows with the same date for the same Sheet? Also, I imagine that SheetA, SheetB... 's records should be sorted by this field, too? Finally, and just for the record, please remember next time to attach example Sheets documents rather than images. ;)

Comment: Hey Carl, thanks for reaching out! To answer your questions:
1) The Date column in the secondary sheets is a timeline, where with each passing month of the year, a new entry will be added for each month. There will only be one record per month.
2) Yes, secondary sheet records will be sorted by Date as time goes by.
3) Sure, I'll see how to attach an example document right away :D

Comment: Why do you not use query, its more simple I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will look for columns in the Sheets A,B... that match columns in the master and append that data for Sheet Names in ColumnA.  It doesn't care how the columns in the sheets are laid out.  So it runs a little slower than assuming a fix layout.  But I was getting bored doing it the same way all of the time.

```
function copyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('MainSheet');
  var mrg=msh.getRange(1,1,msh.getLastRow(),msh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=mrg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){if(e){hObj[e]=i;}});
  vA.forEach(function(row,i){
    if(i>0) {
      var pA=[];
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName(row[hObj['SheetName']]);
      var shA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      var shObj={};
      shA.forEach(function(e,i){if(e){shObj[e]=i;}});
      row.forEach(function(c,j){
        if(shObj.hasOwnProperty(hA[j])) {
          pA.push(c);
        }
      });
      sh.appendRow(pA);
    }
  });
}
```

This is the straight forward way to do it.

```
function copyData1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('MainSheet');
  var mrg=msh.getDataRange();
  var vA=mrg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i>0) {
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName(r[0]);
      sh.appendRow([r[1],r[2],r[3]],r[4]);//Modified for more columns
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you so much for your time and help! I'll give this a try right away.

Comment: Please notice that I appended the straight forward way to do it, which is considerably easier and faster.

Comment: You could do it the simple way for different sheet layouts by using a switch statement on sheet name.

Comment: These are my findings after trying both scripts: 1) Both copy new lines into the secondary sheets instead of using dates that already exist in them. That is no problem and I can work with that perfectly (thanks!). 2) I tried adding a 3rd column in both MainSheet and secondary sheets (Column3), and only copyData() integrated it into the process. For some reason copyData1() ignored the existence of the new column. 3) I also experimented adding a 3rd secondary sheet (SheetC) to the mix, and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: The second version is hard wired. You have change the code if you change the structure. As far the date issue the first version is just copying perhaps there is a problem with formula. If you can share your sheet I’ll fix it

Comment: Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140ZiF4ZibToRgZLWAWl3oSCSohA3vmya5C5UOgu2nO8/edit?usp=sharing) to the sheet

Comment: I used your data in my spreadsheet and it works fine.  So I can't fix what isn't broken.  If you can provide [mcve] then I can fix the problem probably.  i.e. Something that I can run.

Comment: No problem, as mentioned before, script copyData() does the job just fine. I think something is being lost in my explanation since English isn't my first language. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Vital question I guess, how your Sheet A and Sheet B are receiving data? Is it someone who insert data or a script who is doing it?

Comment: Hey Kev, thanks for reaching out. I must have failed at explaining myself, I'll try again. 

The idea is for the macro to copy data from MainSheet to the appropriate cells in the secondary sheets (SheetA and SheetB, in this case). The data on MainSheet will be typed in.

Comment: I got different solution for it then. would you like run the function after each row you've typed in or for example each day ...?

Comment: I've no problem running the script daily, once a large amount of entries have been collected in the MainSheet

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet A put this formula:

```
=QUERY(MainSheet!A:D,"select * where A='Sheet A'",-1)
```

In sheet B put this formula:

```
=QUERY(MainSheet!A:D,"select * where A='Sheet B'",-1)
```

And you can do this in your macro or google app script too

Comment: Sadly using queries from MainSheet isn't an option, cause we'll be doing monthly wipes of it.

Comment: OK I see, but may be it will be as alternative, where from the query you can copy the result to the place, so the query just as an interface.

Comment: I have create for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Here as I said before to use Query, and this automatically create your sheet and get the next date:

```
function CopyDataFromMainSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mysheet;
  mysheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MainSheet');
  //8 is spare columns that may be can used
  var myrange=mysheet.getRange('A1').offset(0, mysheet.getLastColumn()+8);
  myrange.setFormula('=Query(MainSheet!A2:A' + mysheet.getLastRow() + ',"Select A ,count(A) Group By A",0)'); 
  var jojo=mysheet.getRange(1,myrange.getColumn(),mysheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  //Clear Query
  myrange.clear();
  for  (a=1 ;a<jojo.length;a++){
    //Create New Sheet That Not found included with header
    if(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0])==null) if (jojo[a][0]!='') {
      spreadsheet.insertSheet(jojo[a][0]);
      spreadsheet.getRange('MainSheet!1:1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0]).getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }

    if(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0])!=null) if (jojo[a][0]!='') {
      var myDate=new Date('1 jan 1900');

      var DestLastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0]).getLastRow();
      if (DestLastRow>1) myDate=new Date(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0]).getRange('B' + DestLastRow).getValue());
      var dateStr = [
                  myDate.getFullYear(),
                  ('0' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                  ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2)
               ].join('-');
      myrange.setFormula('=Query(MainSheet!A:E,"Select * where A=\'' + jojo[a][0] + '\' and B>date \'' + dateStr + '\'",0)'); 

      var RsltRange=myrange.getA1Notation() + ":" + 
          mysheet.getRange("A1").offset(mysheet.getLastRow()-1,
          mysheet.getLastColumn()-1).getA1Notation();
      //Copy Value
      spreadsheet.getRange('MainSheet!' + RsltRange).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0]).getRange("A"+DestLastRow), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      //copy format
      spreadsheet.getRange('MainSheet!' + RsltRange).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(jojo[a][0]).getRange("A"+DestLastRow), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

      myrange.clear();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I'll go through this and see if it helps, thank you very much! :)

Comment: sorry, myrange.clear() must be un-commented, I have edited it